# Double integral: domain with function

Tags: calculus

and happy new year!

I'm working on a double integra where there is a function at the domain: cos(x)

$ \int_D $ at the domaine $ \{(x,y) | 0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \text{ and } 0 \leq y \leq cos(x) \}  $

Which I have written as

$\int_0^{cos(x)}\int_0^{\pi/2} x \; dx dy $

But: Does this mean I have to integrate w.r.t the dy part first? (normally I would do dx first)

Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

No, you are supposed to integrate dy first, and then over dx, as you have set it your integral as a type-1 region, where y is bounded between two different functions of x. ( y=cos(x) and y=0 in your case).

Had you rewritten the function as a type-2 regions, where x is bounded by two functions of y, the correct approach would have been to integrate it over dx first and then dy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Ok, so dy first. Just to be sure, is the order $\int_0^{cosx} \int_0^{pi/2} x \; dxdy $ still correct?

Comment: No, write it with the dy term preceding the dx term. In this way, you are less likely to make mistakes. If you put dx before dy, you might just 'accidentally' integrate x first from 0 to pi/2, which would be completely wrong as described above.